# Trying to remove null bytes but deleting all my text

Tags: python, python-3.x, null, data-cleaning

So I'm trying to remove null bytes from some text.
I wrote three functions that I think do the same thing.
They all end up giving me blank files and erasing all input.

Here is the example input with a null byte:

```
T:  14/01/2015 22:27:05**\00**||||END_OF_RECORD <- ** so you can see it (I can see it in my ubuntu text editor)
T:  14/01/2015 22:27:05 ||||END_OF_RECORD <- what my IDE shows is a box there
```

Here is the code I wrote to try and fix the files, but they just end up blank.

```
from pathlib import Path

# Removes null bytes from the txt files
def removeNULLBytes():
    for p in workspace.glob('*.csv'):
        new = Path(workspace, p.name)
        new = new.with_suffix('.csv')
        with p.open() as infile, new.open('wb') as outfile:
            fileName = infile.name
            with open(fileName, 'rb') as in_file:
                data = in_file.read()
                # data = str(data, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
                data = (data.replace(b'\x00', b''))
                outfile.write(data)


def removeNULLs():
    for p in workspace.glob('*.csv'):
        new = Path(workspace, p.name)
        new = new.with_suffix('.csv')
        with p.open() as infile, new.open('w') as outfile:
            fileName = infile.name
            with open(fileName, 'r') as in_file:
                data = in_file.read()
                # data = str(data, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
                data = (data.replace(u"\u0000", ""))
                outfile.write(data)

def removeNull():
    for p in workspace.glob('*.csv'):
        new = Path(workspace, p.name)
        new = new.with_suffix('.csv')
        with p.open() as infile, new.open('w') as outfile:
            for line in infile.read():
                newline = ''.join([i if not u"\u0000" else "" for i in line])
                data = (line.replace(line, newline))
                outfile.writelines(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    workspace = Path('/home/')
    # removeNULLBytes()
    removeNull()
    # removeNULLs()
```

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to decode the file contents to **text** before trying to remove any null characters. For many codecs, null bytes are part of the normal encoding, so you shouldn't try to remove them: `'abc'.encode('utf-16')` -> `b'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00c\x00'`.

Comment: Before you attempt to do anything like this, you should verify that the **decoded text** actually contains null characters, e.g. `'\x00' in open(filename, 'r').read()`.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I tried running this on the original text files:
(I converted them to csv) str.encode(encoding = 'UTF-8',errors = 'strict') 
But when I open the file with the built in text editor I still see the error:
"The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again."

I'm pretty sure the null bytes aren't supposed to be there and are from the conversion from the original rich text docs with some crap formatting the original app input created (see above input).

Comment: One way or another, you will have to decode the file using the correct encoding (which is obviously not utf-8). How are the original files created? What do you use to "convert" them to csv?